# Update nested props in array of objects in Redux reducer

Tags: object, redux, react-redux, immutability

Here's the final data signature that I am saving in redux store.

```
const finalDataFormInReduxStore = {
  "id": "123",
  "id_details": [
    {
      "user_city": "SF",

    },
    {
      "user_city": "SF",
    }
}
```

Here's my simple action

```
export const updateUserCity = (index, city) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: {
      index,
      city
    }
  };
};
```

The following reducer works where I am making the ***id_details*** property to be an object (but I wanted this prop to be an array as per my target data signature in redux store. )

```
case UPDATE_USER :  {
  return {
    ...state,
      id_details: {
        ...state.id_details,
        [actions.payload.index]: {
          ...state.id_details[actions.payload.index],
          user_city: actions.payload.city
        }
      }
  };
}
```

But, when I make ***id_details*** property to be an array the following reducer does NOT work . (which is what I wanted as per my target data signature in redux store. )

```
case UPDATE_USER :  {
  return {
    ...state,
      id_details: [
        ...state.id_details,
        [actions.payload.index]: {
          ...state.id_details[actions.payload.index],
          user_city: actions.payload.city
        }
      ]
  };
}
```

I have looked at this [**github issue page**](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/432#issuecomment-363958117) for guidance, but did not help me .  Probably I am missing something basic here.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what specifically isn't working? What error are you receiving? Can you provide the action for `UPDATE_USER` instead of `UPDATE_USER_CITY`?

Comment: @DrewReese I corrected the action for UPDATE_USER instead of UPDATE_USER_CITY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array the easiest way to do this is by mapping over the array:

```
case UPDATE_USER : {
  return {
    ...state,
    id_details: state.id_details.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === actions.payload.index) {
        return {...item, user_city: actions.payload.city};
      }
      return item;
    }),
  };
}
```